# not able to forward values calculated in a servlet to a jsp page using RequestDispatcher.How to do the same?

Tags: java, servlets

In my code..i have retrieved the value of input(text type) from a jsp page in a servlet using `request.getParameter()`.

Now using these values,i have performed some calculation.
now i want to forward the calculated value (i.e. the result) as well as the operands.. i e. the retrieved value to a new jsp page. I am doing this by setting the values using `request.setAttribute()` and forwarding to the destined jsp page using `getRequestDispatcher().forward(request,response)`.

But my page is not being forwarded.

```
package imsf;  

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import Service;  

public class CalcPurRate extends HttpServlet {
    String iname;
    String cname;
    String mrate;
    String irate;
    String disR;
    String disP;
    String newAdd;
    String q;
    int imr;
    int iir;
    int idR;
    int idP;
    String dP;
    String dR;
    int ina;
    int iprate;
    int total;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
           String in=request.getParameter("iname");
           out.print("my name"+in);
           String cn=request.getParameter("cname");
           out.print("my cate"+cn);

          if(request.getParameter("mrate")!=null)
          {
            String mr=request.getParameter("mrate");
              if(!(mr.equals(null)))
              {
               imr=Integer.parseInt(mr);
               out.print(" mrp= "+imr);
              }
          }
          if(request.getParameter("irate")!=null)
          {
            String ir=request.getParameter("irate");
              if(!(ir.equals(null)))
              {
               iir=Integer.parseInt(ir);
               out.print("invoice= "+iir);
              }
          }
         if(request.getParameter("disR")!=null)
         {
            out.print("disR not null");
            dR=request.getParameter("disR");
            if(!(dR.equals(null))) 
            {
             out.print("disR not zero");
             idR=Integer.parseInt(dR);
             /*if(request.getParameter("disP")==null)
                 {
                   out.print("disP not zero");
                   dP=request.getParameter("disP");
                     if(dP.equals(null))
                     {
                       out.print("disP not zero");
                        iprate=((iir)-(idR));
                        out.print("iprate="+iprate);
                     }
                 }*/
              out.print("integer dis R="+idR);
              iprate=((iir)-(idR));
              out.print("iprate="+iprate);
           }
         }
          /*if(request.getParameter("disP")!=null)
          {
              out.print("disP not null");
              dP=request.getParameter("disP");
              if(!(dP.equals(null)))
               {
                out.print("disP value="+dP);
                out.print("disP not zero");
                /*if(request.getParameter("disR")==null)
                  {
                   dR=request.getParameter("disR");
                   if(dR.equals(null))
                    {
                     idP=Integer.parseInt(dP);
                     out.print("integer dis P="+idP);
                     iprate=((iir)-(((idP)*(iir))/100));
                     out.print("pur rate"+iprate);
                    }
                  }*/
              //}
              //}
           /*if(idR!=0)
           {
               out.print("innn");
               iprate=((iir)-(idR));
               out.print("pur rate"+iprate);
           }
           out.print("heheh");

           if(idP!=0)
           {
               iprate=iir-((idP*iir)/100);
               out.print("vgfhg"+iprate);
           }*/
           if(request.getParameter("newAdd")!=null)
           {
               String na=request.getParameter("newAdd");
               if(!(na.equals(null)))
              {
              ina=Integer.parseInt(na);
              total=((ina)*(iprate));
              out.print("total="+total);
              }
           }
           request.setAttribute("purRate",iprate);
           request.setAttribute("total",total);
           //response.sendRedirect("ItemDetail.jsp");
           RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/ItemDetail.jsp");
           rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          e.getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What you're doing seems to be the right thing. You should provide some code so that we can look into the details.

Answer (score 1):

`processRequest()` is not a method that has any meaning to an `HttpServlet`.  Your servlet is actually doing nothing whatsoever - `processRequest()` will not be invoked by anything.

You should be implementing either `doGet()` or `doPost()`, and put your logic in there.

Incidentally, storing data in fields of a servlet like this is an *extremely* bad idea. It's not thread-safe  - multiple concurrent requests will corrupt your servlet's state.

Comment: @skaffman..thanx for ur advice..but i want to share sumthing..i have implemented other codes too in d same way as above (i.e..in processRequest()..and they have worked out well.i want to know why this code is not working..hope i may get ur help...

Comment: @tammanna: I have no idea without seeing it. The code you posted won't work, that's all I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to land in a new page, just use the sendRedirect() method.
by the way the details that you have provided looks correct.
try to get the parameters at the destination jsp and let us know.. it should work..

HTH

Comment: @Ayusman...I want to get forwarded to a new page along with the values calculated in d servlet...using SendRedirect() only a new request will be made and the vlaues will not b forwarded.using RequestDispatcher().forward(req,res),i m not getting the values at d destinaltion page..anticipating for ur help..